# How to link customers and suppliers in a database

Tags: mysql, database-design, optimization, mysql-5.7

Some customers can be suppliers at the same time, so: how to design the database so we don't have two tables having the same columns, and, at the same time, we can link a customer and a supplier together if needed?

Answer (score 0):

In the customers table I think you can add an extra column which would flag whether that customer is also a supplier.  So you could have a generic customer table (or you can name it contacts table), with a column used as a supplier flag/indicator (could be numeric: 1 or 0 or char: y or n or even boolean: true or false)

[image]

Comment: And probably a good idea to add a history table so if the contact was originally a customer, became a customer and supplier then changed to just a supplier then historical records would still be valid

Comment: Like this there is no link between customer and supplier we are just adding a flag. Notice that the customers and suppliers maybe added to different tables.

Comment: @HmH - Think of them as "People" (or "Contacts", as VC suggested).  The extra column says what role they perform.  It could even be `SET('customer', 'supplier')`.  Some other columns may be `NULLable` if they apply only to a customer, not a supplier (or vice versa).